# Is it possible to create a signal in LTSpice by using a stored data?

Tags: ltspice

I have lots of sampled voltage signals data where I can plot them in MATLAB or write them to a text file for each sample.

I would like to use these samples to generate input signals in LTSpice instead of trying to mimic them.

Is it doable in LTSpice?

edit: My data samples on txt can be in the following format:

59.7435           5.0615

59.7437    5.0578

59.7440    5.0768

59.7443    5.1119

Where the first column is time stamps in seconds, and the second column is corresponding sampled voltages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can format the matlab data as a series of timestamps and levels  you can use the PWL file option for a voltage or current source.

http://www.linear.com/solutions/1814

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is uniformly sampled, which it looks like it is, I would personally use the function in LTspice to read WAVE files.

To use it, add a voltage source to your circuit and as the voltage expression you enter:

```
wavefile="C:\path\to\your\file.wav" chan=0
```

This will reproduce the sampled signal efficiently with minimum storage space.

Comment: not wave file mine are txt files

Comment: @user16307, then you can translate your data into a wav file. You should be able to do this in  Matlab or whatever programming language you like, with a little research on the WAV format.

Comment: why would i convert to wav if LTspice can already  read txt?

Comment: wav files (may) use less disk space, this could be a game changer for complicated signals.

Comment: @user16307 Because you used the expression _write them to a text file_, I assumed that you had the data in some kind of raw, non-text format, and to make a text file you had to convert it anyway. If the dataset is tiny, and already in a file format that PWL can read, there's no need to convert it.

Comment: @pipe .wav files are limited to +/-1V, even if they do support up to 32bit resolution. Trying to attenuate (fit within limits), then amplify back the signal will come with a loss of precision. In this case, PWL is the way.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Note that the user is using _sampled data_. It is unlikely that it has a resolution exceeding 32 bits. The magnitude is not related to the resolution.

Comment: @pipe I should have said dynamic range, but even so, it is directly related to the magnitude. It wouldn't be the same to have an 8bit signal compared to a 32bit one, and converting (twice) the amplitude to fit the +/-1V for .wav file and then back to have full scale will come at a cost. This is what I meant to say, maybe my words didn't come out right. Still, sampled data is sampled data, so there should be extra care not to lose the already quantized values by division/multiplication. I am not dismissing the .wav file as a solution, just that in this case, a PWL would be better, imho.